# Remove string value after HTML delimiter from database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm currently migrating my website to a different platform.  Inside my database, I have a column named `excerpt` which is supposed to contain just the intro text from my blog posts. After migrating my database, I've come to find that my `excerpt` column and my `content` column are duplicates of each other with identical values. The basic schema looks as follows:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | title       | excerpt                                     | content |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | This post.  |<p>Text I want.</p><p>Text I don't want.</p> |<p>Text..|
2  | That post.  |<p>Text I want.</p><p>Text I don't want.</p> |<p>Text..|
3  | Next post.  |<p>Text I want.</p><p>Text I don't want.</p> |<p>Text..|
4  | What post?  |<p>Text I want.</p><p>Text I don't want.</p> |<p>Text..|
5  | Whose post? |<p>Text I want.</p><p>Text I don't want.</p> |<p>Text..|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I'd like to know is, in the `excerpt` column, how can I remove everything after the first `</p>` occurrence? I've been searching for a solution over the last few days and the only thing I've come across is REGEXP in SQL but I'm still rather new to writing query commands.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    excerpt,
    substring(excerpt, 0, locate('</p>', excerpt) + char_length('</p>')) 
from 
    your_table
```

**EDIT:**

```
select 
    excerpt,
    substring_index(excerpt, '</p>', 1) 
from 
    your_table
```

Comment: It's giving me the following error message: `FUNCTION myDatabase.charindex does not exist`

Comment: Sorry! You using MySql... Try to use function `LOCATE` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)

Comment: When I run it like this `substring(excerpt, 0, locate('</p>', excerpt, 0) + len('</p>'))` I now get this message: `FUNCTION myDatabase.len does not exist`

Comment: I changed my answer with MySql syntax.

Comment: No errors but all of my excerpts are still the same.

Comment: I don't have any MySql server right now to check my query. Try to use SUBSTRING_INDEX (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)